# Destructuring object based on another value in redux state

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, destructuring

The application has two different tabs, each with identical drop-downs. I am currently saving the 'selectedTab' which is a string, and the 'selectedTabState' which is an object containing both tab1 and tab2, and a string of which selection the user has chosen. I am able to view which tab the user is on, while also saving the drop-down state while switching between tabs. Here is an example of what it looks like.

```
selectedTab: 'tab1'
selectedTabState: {
  tab1: 'dropdownOptionOne',
  tab2: 'dropdownOptionTwo'
}
```

What I would like to do is access the selectedTabState of whatever tab the user is on using destructuring. Can I do something like this?

```
const { selectedStates: { *state of selectedTab* }} = state;
```

Comment: Why not just `selectedStates[selectedTab]`? Don't complicate things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring) with destrcuturing like this

```js
const state = {
  selectedTab: 'tab1',
  selectedTabState: {
    tab1: 'dropdownOptionOne',
    tab2: 'dropdownOptionTwo'
  }
}

const { selectedTabState: { [state.selectedTab]: value } } = state;

console.log(value)
```

But, as Brian Le suggested, `state.selectedTabState[state.selectedTab]` is much more simpler

Answer (score 0):

```
const state = selectedTab === 'tab1' ? selectedTabState.tab1 : selectedTabState.tab2
```

Would this work for you